# Custom server prefix error discord.py bot

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots

If i want to run the code and enter in my discord server `+prefix !` comes the following error message:

line 13, in get_prefix
return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]
KeyError: '848927731752239108'

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import random
import json



def get_prefix(client,message):

    with open("prefixes.json", "r") as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)
    return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]
```

What does this error mean and how can i fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: It means that `848927731752239108` is not in the dictionary.

Comment: pls edit your Question and add `prefixes.json`.

Answer (score 1):

This error means that id is not in the dictionary of ids and prefixs.

To fix this make sure your bot will automatically add servers to the list with a default prefix. There's a great youtube video on that here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yrHbGhem6I4

Have a great day!